# Is it right to host my application in windows azure?

Tags: windows, azure

Friends. I am new to windows azure concept. Just i want to knw whether we can host my asp.net application developed in visual studio 2010 with sql server 2008 or i need to develop my application in windows azure environment?

ii). Whether they provide both hosting and storage?

if it so what are the steps to implement it as a beginner?

Please can any one suggest a clear idea about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty generic question. To get started, I strongly suggest downloading the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) which will guide you through all the basics through advanced topics.

You can absolutely run asp.net apps and SQL Server apps in Windows Azure. You'll need to think about things like statelessness, scaling, and other things that might be different from an on-premises solution. You should see these topics discussed in the training kit.

Last week, [Windows Azure Web Sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/) was introduced - this is an extremely simple way to deploy an asp.net site to Windows Azure.

As far as "is it right to host my application in windows Azure" - that type of question doesn't fit here, as it will simply open the floor for debate.

Comment: Thanks. David. I am in somewhat critical situation. Can you give some guidance regarding this. I want speed up my data and appl. So as per you suggestion only i will plan to do host my application in windows azure.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what advice I can give. There are dozens of things to think about when developing a Windows Azure app. I even enumerated several of these in [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11059938/272109), which might be a good initial list of topics to think about.